# Where and how disable dynamodb "missing data" Cloudwatch alarms

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

In the billing management console, it states that I've used 57.510 alarms. Looking at these alarms, they all come from dynamodb tables and are either INSUFFICIENT_DATA or OK alerts, e.g.

```
INSUFFICIENT_DATA / TargetTracking-table/profile-preferences-AlarmLow-0626754b-aa9a-4883-839b-as4c3c012078 / ConsumedReadCapacityUnits < 60 for 15 datapoints within 15 minutes

OK / TargetTracking-table/profile-preferences-ProvisionedCapacityHigh-48338eb0-b2b0-4f05-bafb-5c4b72721bc2 / ProvisionedWriteCapacityUnits > 2 for 3 datapoints within 15 minutes
```

I've read here ([Avoiding INSUFFICIENT DATA in Cloudwatch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33639642/avoiding-insufficient-data-in-cloudwatch)) that these alarms can be avoided by ignore missing data.

**The question is where and how to set the option to ignore missing data for dynamodb table alarms**. I've looked at the corresponding tables (e.g. profile-preferences) in dynamodb and can't find any alerts set up. In the corresponding alarms in CloudWatch the description tells me not to edit the alarm:

```
DO NOT EDIT OR DELETE. For TargetTrackingScaling policy arn:aws:autoscaling:eu-central-1:110845280302:scalingPolicy:6f31d04d-f1b2-4299-bd5a-8ac18142a74c:resource/dynamodb/table/profile-preferences:policyName/DynamoDBWriteCapacityUtilization:table/profile-preferences.
```

Any ideas how and where to disable/avoid these alarms being created?

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS console for DynamoDB, select your table, then select the "Alarms" tab.  For each alarm, select it to display the edit modal, then change "Treat Missing Data As" to "ignore (maintain alarm state)".[image]